# Django: Use default template tags in view functions

Tags: django

I want to reuse the code of default template tags in my view functions, as i can use the default filters in views.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import default, urlencode, iriencode
title = default(title_str, "N/A")
..
```

here is my 
*url.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
     url(r"^artist/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$", "app_name.views.artist_details", name="artist_details"),
 )
```

when i use `reverse` in views,

```
reverse("artist_details", args=[artist.slug])
```

app crashed bcoz `slug` has Japanese, and it gives `Exception Type: NoReverseMatch` error,

So either i can use the code of `{% url %}` in my *view.py* OR any other suggestion?

**[updated]**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse)

Comment: i know of it, but my url have Japanese slug, so using `reverse` app crashed :(

Comment: @Ahsan What was the error? Where? `{% url %}` tag is just call of `reverse` so if first works, second will work too.

Comment: here artist slug has Japanese in it, when I make the url in template it works fine. `{% url artist_details artist.slug as artist_url %}` `{{artist_url|iriencode}}` but when I want to make the url through views bu using `reverse`. `reverse("artist_details", args=[artist.slug])` then app crashed, error is `Reverse for 'artist_details' with arguments '(u'\u785d\u5b50\u306e\u56fd\u304b\u3089\u306e\u30d7\u30ec\u30bc\u30f3\u30c8Vol.23',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in your view:

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode, iri_to_uri
reverse("artist_details",args=[force_unicode(iri_to_uri(artist.slug))])
```

Comment: this also gives *Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch*

Comment: if you look at code of `iriencode` in defaultfilters, its same as you did it, but this also crash the app :(